# Capturing table data from Tableau dashboards in Java

Tags: java, automation, ocr, tableau-api, uipath

Is there a way to automatically capture and store data from a tableau dashboard without access to the server.

I'm trying to automate a lot of our weekly audits (i.e. look at the dashboard, count the number of rows on a table, sum up the values in the last column, send out an email to everyone in the same template every week). I need basic functionality such as counting rows and pulling values from certain cells.

I do not have access to tabcmd (corporate blah blah).

I've previously automated Salesforce stuff in Selenium, however, the tableau dashboard is a visualization and not a web element.

I have investigated a few potential routes and was wondering if anyone else could chime in on the best way to approach this (or suggest another).

1. Use an OCR package to try and recognize values and sum up rows
2. I somehow automate the report downloading process so I can turn all the data into an excel/CSV file which I can play within Java
3. Use RPA tool such as UIPath (don't have much experience with the functionality but it seems like it could do it?)

Comment: Regarding UiPath, just give it a try: https://www.uipath.com/developers/community-edition

Comment: Yep have it downloaded and will have a look at it over the weekend. Wanted to grab everyone's opinions on the best approach to this situation before dedicating time to learning it.